# How to remove a html tag in a custom listview created using volley

Tags: android, html, listview, android-fragments

I am using volley library to display a custom listview in my android application.

In the individual list the text is displaying these html tag also

```
<h3><span style='font-weight: bold;'>Open Day</span><br><br></h3><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit...
```

I don't know how to remove it. I already searched in Stackoverflow and tried to fix it using the given solution. like

```
public String stripHtml(String html) 
{
return Html.fromHtml(html).toString();
}
```

etc. But none works for me. I am using Navigation drawer and fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try the following, create class in your package and name it "Util"

```
public class Util{
public static String stripHtml(String html) 
{
  //html = "<p sapn = 'div'>hhhhhhhhh<p> Hello World </p></span>";
  while(html.contains("<"))
    html = html.replace(html.substring(html.indexOf("<"),html.indexOf(">")+1),"");
  return html;//will return hhhhhhhh Hello World
}
}
```

this method will search for any text that begins with "<" and ends with ">" and it will replace it.

then you can use the method anywhere you want

```
String myNewStringWithoutHTML = Util.stripHtml(STRING);
```

Comment: its 100% working, I'm using it in alot of applications that read html pages from the internet, you can track your code in the log screen by System.out.println(); keep printing data and analyze it

Comment: What String I need to replace. Html tags are still getting display in some part of my app.

Comment: can you please post the content of the html

Comment: actually this is my json link http://imaginetventures.net/sample/everwin_vidhyashram/webservice/rest/?module=academic&class=6 I want to show this content in list. The <br><p> tags are getting displayed in list. I want to remove it.

Comment: man the method that I gave you works fine... go to [link](http://ideone.com/kvhHSv) I've compiled the code on online java compiler, checkout the output

Comment: Sorry for the late reply bro. Its working like a charm. Thanks a lot for this.